# Styling string from Viewmodel in Windows 8 metro

Tags: c#, string, mvvm, windows-8

I am following MVVM pattern for my project and wanted to bind a string property to a TextBlock Text property.I want some of the words in the string property hace different color like

**User** has completed the **Survey**

I am not getting how to achieve this multicolored string in viewmodel.
I wanted this should happen in viewmodel because this message is dependent on conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Run property

non mvvm

```
        <Run Foreground="Blue">User</Run>
        <Run Foreground="Black">has completed the</Run>
        <Run Foreground="Blue">Survey</Run>
    </TextBlock>
```

or Mvvm you could have your view model format the strings and then just bind to the relevant properties

```
 <TextBlock>            
        <Run Text={Binding your_mvvm_property}"  Foreground="{StaticResource your_style"/>
        <Run Text={Binding your_mvvm_property2}"  Foreground="{StaticResource your_style2"/>
    </TextBlock>
```